# Lua for loop control variable

Tags: lua

I need to be able to advance my for loop control index variable - from within the loop

```
for i=1,5 do
   io.write(("i: %d; "):format(i))
   i = i + 2 -- this has no effect, as 'for' is in control of the index var.
end
```

Comment: You can't modify the control variable. Use a separate variable or use a step as in `for i=1,5,2`

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you to use 'while'.

```
local i = 1
while i <= 5 do
  io.write(("i: %d; "):format(i))
  i = i + 2 -- it works
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
local i = 1
while true do
  if i > 5 then break end -- or an other condition to end the loop
  io.write(("i: %d; "):format(i))
  i = i + 2 -- it works
end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).